# XQuery : get only one XML element among many with the same name

Tags: xml, geolocation, xquery

I'm using this URL to get information of a given location (with latitude/longitude) :

> http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?latlng=48.845909,2.341762&sensor=true

What I want to do is to get the basic address of this place (address, town). So I tried this XQuery request :

```
let $lat := 48.845909,
$lng := 2.341762,
$url := concat('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?latlng=',$lat,',',$lng,'&#38;sensor=true'),
$resp := doc($url)
return $resp//result/formatted_address/string()
```

But with this I get all the **formatted_address** elements of the XML result, so here I get :

```
12 Rue Royer-Collard, 75005 Paris, France
Val-de-Grâce, Paris, France
75005 Paris, France
5th arrondissement of Paris, Paris, France
Paris, France
Paris, France
Île-de-France, France
France
```

And I only want the first line. What should I do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use [1] to get the first element.:

```
let $lat := 48.845909,
$lng := 2.341762,
$url := concat('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?latlng=',$lat,',',$lng,'&#38;sensor=true'),
$resp := doc($url)
return ($resp//result/formatted_address/string())[1]
```

Or move it to the first result (probably faster):

```
let $lat := 48.845909,
$lng := 2.341762,
$url := concat('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?latlng=',$lat,',',$lng,'&#38;sensor=true'),
$resp := doc($url)
return $resp//result[1]/formatted_address/string()
```